# IE - sub menu disappearing

Tags: internet-explorer, menu

I have this strange problem that submenu's show up normally in Chrome and Firefox but - most of the time - disappear in IE.

Example: http://www.voorouder.nl/genealogie/suggest.php

in IE, hover over genealogie, albums or contacts (they have sub menu's). As soon as you try to hover over the items in the sub menu - most of the time - the whole sub menu disappears.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem so it isn't isolated.  Can you show us the code that you use to make the drop down menu?

Answer (score 0):

In your "mytngstyle.css" file, try changing the padding-top setting of "#nav li ul" to 0px instead of 1px.  It seems like you are getting a 1 pixel space between your main menu item and the sub-menu `<ul>`.

If the padding doesn't fix it look closely at some of the other settings to see why your getting that 1px space between the two `<ul>`'s.